# Usage of Apache Flink and RxJava

Tags: rx-java, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm currently using Apache flink and using RxJava inside of it, my questions is: Using both of them is appropriate? because my flink operations are always map functions and inside of them I use Rx intensively, like take the tuples from flink and make asynchronous  operations with them (Go to DB, write to a queue and so on), But I don't ended up using most of the methods that flink expose to me and my programs steps returns json when Rxjava ends with the processing.

Can you tell me if that is a correct usage of flink or if there is aa better way of do what I need to do. (like use it but pass the observables between flink steps or something like that).

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flink has powerful tools to handle state (e.g. in windows) [1,2], which often makes it possible to avoid calls to other systems. For example, instead of handling state in an external key-value store, you could use (checkpointed) KeyValueState in Flink. Handling the state inside of Flink is usually more efficient/faster than calling external systems/databases.

A problem with asynchronous calls in Flink programs can be that Flink is faster than then the called systems, which result in increasing number of open futures, ultimately leading to memory problems. So, I think, it is generally suggested to use synchronous calls inside of Flink operators to slow down Flink to the speed of the called systems to avoid memory leaks.

The last point has been recently discussed on the mailing list: http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/flink-user/201606.mbox/%3CCALrNVjVw=iu7PB76VmKk+BD6rDXfSDwxpMrtzk8=L5d8xE-o8Q@mail.gmail.com%3E

[1] https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.0/apis/streaming/windows.html
[2]https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.0/apis/streaming/state.html

Answer (score 0):

The current answer still holds for keeping state within Flink where possible, though if you still need to access external systems there are performant [Async I/O methods](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/operators/asyncio.html). Async Operators hook into Flink’s lifecycle and manage the number of concurrent Async requests, hopefully curbing memory issues.